# Adobe XD Storage APIs - Get the current XD document file path location

Tags: adobe-xd

If I place an adobe xd document anywhere on my local computer.

Example: `C:\doc\adobe-xd\brand\brand.xd`

Open it and run a plugin

Is it possible to retrieve the adobe xd document location.

P.S I'm not having any trouble getting the plugin or plugin setting locations

**Edit**

Found an answer on [adobexdplatform](https://adobexdplatform.com/plugin-docs/reference/uxp/storage-index.html)

```
// These require no user interaction:
const tempFolder = await fs.getTemporaryFolder();
const pluginFolder = await fs.getPluginFolder();  // read-only access to the plugin's install folder
const pluginDataFolder = await fs.getDataFolder();  // folder to store settings

// Display file/folder picker UI to access user files:
const userFolder = await fs.getFolder();  // folder picker
const aFile = await fs.getFileForOpening();  // "Open" file picker, suitable for reading contents
const anotherFile = await fs.getFileForSaving("hello.txt");  // "Save" file picker, suitable for writing contents
```

Comment: The "found answer on adobexdplatform" is not really an answer to the original question. It is everything that's possible though. I just browsed through the whole docs and found nothing. Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 5):

There isn't currently an API to tell you the name or location on disk of the current XD document, but bear in mind that there can be Untitled documents for which name/location isn't available anyway.

If you're just curious how a plugin can get access to an arbitrary location on disk *in general* (not necessarily the .xd document file), then the API documentation you found is correct: you can launch a file open/save dialog box to gain access to other files from the user. This is similar to the permissions model in Mac App Store and Windows Store apps.

Comment: Is there any plan to add such an API @peterflynn? It was possible in CAAPI and could really be helpful with certain things like versioning XD files (git-like branches), syncing them to cloud storage for sharing, etc.

Or if you don't wanna share the file path, could we at least save the current XD file  to a tmp location somehow? (renditions only generate a PNG/PDF, not a XD file).